# Preserve form data when using history.go(-1)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have 
insert.php
verify.php

in Insert.php I have a form with some fields and some other fields which are generated by ajax calls based on selections. I also have an image uploader where the image is uploaded to the server as soon as the user chooses the image. The preview of the image is then showed when upload is done.  When the form is submitted, it sends form.serialize to verify.php.

In verify.php the user sees and verifies the data from insert.php form. 
If user thinks that everything is correct then he can submit it. or click on the "Edit" button to go back. When going back some of the info are not available. fields that are generated through ajax are not available.

Anyway to fix it ?

I add element to insert.php using

```
$('#subcategoryPlaceHolder').html(result);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of verify.php?

Comment: For your edit button, parse another form with hidden entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using two divs.

```
#editDiv and #verifyDiv
```

using jquery I hid the one I didnt need and the form data was there all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your app completely, but when working with data like this it's generally a bad idea to go use the back function in the browser.

A better solution would be to save the data that needs to be remembered into the session, and when a user clicks Edit it reloads the form using the data stored in the session, without submitting the form. When a user thinks everything is correct they can submit the form, saving the data, and then you can delete the session data.